# Mac OS Sierra log show missing SSH source IP

Tags: macos-sierra

Before, we can track all the SSH logins either success/failure in OS X El Capitan.   When moved to OS Sierra, It seems that all the logs were moved which can be viewed by log show, log stream, and syslog.
We can't track the source IP of an SSH process by looking those logs. e.g. :

```
Jun 27 15:38:47 MAC sshd: administrator [priv][240] <Notice>: USER_PROCESS: 243 ttys000
Jun 27 15:39:34 MAC sshd: administrator [priv][249] <Notice>: USER_PROCESS: 257 ttys001
Jun 27 15:42:50 MAC sshd: administrator [priv][249] <Notice>: DEAD_PROCESS: 257 ttys001
```

Screen sharing logs works perfectly just like before:

```
screensharingd: Authentication: SUCCEEDED :: User Name: administrator :: Viewer Address: 10.X.X.X :: Type: DH
```

Though we can see the logs of sshd if the attempt failed:

```
 sshd: error: PAM: authentication error for administrator from 10.10.5.73
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this command:

```
log stream --info --predicate 'processImagePath contains[c] "sshd"'
```

It will log the successful and failed attempts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll just need to catch the output from log stream so that I can store them in a single file.

Comment: Similar issues but instead of file we needed to push those ssh logs to external system. Glad that the answer was helpful.

Comment: Yeah, we're planning on building a syslog server in the near future, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that SSH logs can be shown using this command:

```
log show --style JSON | grep "ssh"
```

Answer (score 0):

This command will show SSH login attempts with source IP stored in ram.

```
log show --predicate 'process == "sshd"' --info | grep 'Info'
```